# A two-dimensional recurrence relation with non-constant coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to find estimates for partial derivatives of a function. While I have found the parts containing the asymptotics, I am struggling to find the correct coefficients.
My calculations have led me to the recurrence relation

\begin{equation}
y^{m+1}_{c+1} = \left( m + 2 c \right) y^m_{c+1} + y^m_c
\end{equation}

for $m, c \in \mathbb{N}$ with the boundary conditions

\begin{aligned}
y^1_2 &= 1 \\
y^1_{2+n} &= 0 \\
y^m_1 &= 0
\end{aligned}

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
It can be viewed as a generalized Pascal triangle where one of the items in the previous row is multiplied by a non-constant factor. (The troublesome factor comes from the application of a partial derivative to a monomial)

I seem to be unable to solve the recurrence relation. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried computing the generating function, i.e. $ \sum_{c,m}y_c^m t^c u^m$ or $ \sum_{c,m} y_c^m \frac{t^c u^m}{c!m!} $ ?

Comment: Yes, but I did not get anywhere. Resolving the coefficient $(m+2c)$ requires partial derivatives and the resulting partial differential equation seems even harder to get a grasp on.

Answer (score 1):

$$ y_{c+1}^{m+1} = (m+2c)y_{c+1}^m +y_c^m = (m+2c)[(m-1+2c)y_{c+1}^{m-1} + y_c^{m-1}] + y_{c}^m = ...\quad = (m+2c)_m \cdot  y_{c+1}^1 + \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (m+2c)_{k} \cdot y_{c}^{m-k} $$
where $(x)_k = x(x-1)\cdots (x-k+1) $ is the falling Pochhammer symbol and $(x)_0=1$. If $c>1$, then $y_{c+1}^1 = 0$, hence the first term cancels. 
If $c=1$, then $y_1^m=0$, hence
$$ y_2^{m+1} = (m+2)_m .$$
$$ y_3^{m+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(m+4)_k \cdot y_2^{m-k} $$
From here things get ugly, I'm not sure if there is a nice solution, but I might be wrong.